# SQL Server (2012 Enterprise) Browser service failing

Tags: sql-server, sql, sql-server-2012

SQL Server (2012 Enterprise) Browser service failing

I have a problem as described below:

I have an instance of SQL Server 2012 Enterprise (thanks to MSDN) for local development on my PC.

I try to start SQL server Browser Service from SQL Server Configuration Manager and it takes a long time to fail, then fails with:

> The request failed or the service did not respond in a timely fashion.
>   Consult the event log or other applicable error logs for details.

I checked event logs and found these errors in this order (all within the same 1-second time frame):

> The SQL Server Browser service port is unavailable for listening, or
>   invalid.
>
> The SQL Server Browser service was unable to establish SQL instance
>   and connectivity discovery.
>
> The SQL Server Browser is enabling SQL instance and connectivity
>   discovery support.
>
> The SQL Server Browser service was unable to establish Analysis
>   Services discovery.
>
> The SQL Server Browser service has started.
>
> The SQL Server Browser service has shutdown.

I checked firewall rules and both port 1433 (TCP) and 1434 (UDP) are wide open, just as well - the programs and service binary had been "allowed through windows firewall".
I started the "Analysis Services" service by hand and it works fine. Browser still won't start.

Some History:
Installed SQL 2008 R2 express advanced

Installed SQL2012 Express advanced

Uninstalled SQL 2008 R2 express advanced

Installed 2012 SSDT and lots of features with Express install

Installed a unique instance of SQL 2012 Enterprise with all features

Uninstalled SSDT and reinstalled SSDT with Enterprise (solved a different problem)

Uninstalled SQL 2012 Express

Uninstalled SQL 2012 Enterprise

Removed anything with "SQL" in the name from Control panel > "Programs and features"

Installed SQL 2012 Enterprise without Analysis services (This is where I noticed SQL Browser service was failing to start *even on the install*)

Added the feature of Analysis Services (and everything else) via the installer (Browser continued to fail to start on the install)

========================

Other interesting facts:
opening a command window with administrator and trying to run sqlbrowser.exe manually yielded:

> Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601] Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft
>   Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> C:\Windows\system32>cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\90\Shared
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Shared>sqlbrowser.exe -c 
>   SQLBrowser: starting up in console mode  SQLBrowser: starting up SSRP redirection service
>   SQLBrowser: failed starting SSRP redirection services -- shutting down.
>   SQLBrowser: starting up OLAP redirection service
>   SQLBrowser: Stopping the OLAP redirector
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Shared>

As I try to repair the install it errors out saying

> The following error has occurred:
>
> Service 'SQLBrowser' start request failed.
>
> Click 'Retry' to retry the failed action, or click 'Cancel' to cancel
>   this action and continue setup.
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=20476&ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=11.0.2100.60&EvtType=0x4F9BEA51%25400xD3BEBD98%25401211%25401

Clicking retry fails every time. When clicking cancel I get:

> The following error has occurred:
>
> SQL Server Browser configuration for feature
>   'SQL_Browser_Redist_SqlBrowser_Cpu32' was cancelled by user after a
>   previous installation failure. The last attempted step: Starting the
>   SQL Server Browser service 'SQLBrowser', and waiting for up to '900'
>   seconds for the process to complete. .
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=20476&ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=11.0.2100.60&EvtType=0x4F9BEA51%25400xD3BEBD98%25401211%25401

When I go to uninstall the SQL Browser from "Programs and Features", it complains:

> Error opening installation log file. Verify that the specified log
>   file location exists and is writable.

Is there any way I can fix this short of re-imaging my computer and reinstalling from scratch?
A possible approach would be to somehow *really uninstall **everything*** and delete all files related to SQL... is that a good idea, and how do I do *that*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned that installing Enterprise Edition locally is a bad idea... thus I tried:

- removing everything related to SQL server with "programs and features"
- deleteing all files related to SQL server from Program files (and Program files (x86))
- Installing SQL 2012 Express

SQL Browser service still failed to start, thus failed to install.

I found [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverfaq/archive/2010/08/31/prb-sql-server-browser-service-does-not-start-due-to-winsock-monitoring-software.aspx) which led me to believe I had an interfereing proxy of some kind... sure enough! **I removed Covenant Eyes** (a content filtering service) from my computer, and tried to reinstall SQL Server Express and the browser service installed correctly. Still a handful of other things failed to install (Database Engine Services, Full-Text and Semantic Extractions for Search, SQL Server Replication, Reporting Services - Native), but the browser service is working!

If you are having this issue as well, check for interference from filters/proxies/virus scanners/etc..

UPDATE:

I got the other 4 things (that failed to install) working by going to "Programs and Features" > removing just those features and reinstalling them. I ran into these helpfuls questions along the way:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979425/sql-server-installation-what-is-the-installation-media-folder

If you get the error

> Rule "Reporting Services Catalog Database File Existence" failed

or

> Rule "Reporting Services Catalog Temporary Database File Existence"
>   failed

Go to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL<version#>.<instance_name>\MSSQL\DATA` and delete the report server files.

- ReportServer.mdf
- ReportServer_log.LDF
- ReportServerTempDB.mdf
- ReportServerTempDB_log.LDF.

http://www.sqlcoffee.com/Troubleshooting028.htm